# Работа с фреймами в javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Хорошего Рождества друзья!

Я, пытаюсь понять как можно по нажатию кнопки в html-документе сгенерировать фрейм, в котором будет опять же этот html-документ, но при этом явного указания на имя-источника для фрейма не должно быть, так как родительский файл-html будут переименовывать по-разному.

Кроме того в родительском html-документе есть таблица данных, в фрейме она должна пройти фильтрацию и измениться в итоге. К примеру что-то вроде того: все отрицательные значения в ячейках таблицы фрейма должны стать положительными или строки, где значения первого столбца имеют имя "Василий" должны в фрейме-таблице скрыться... И прочая муть такого рода, привел пару типовых операций какие могут случиться с фреймом.

Пытался:

1. Найти в интернете хорошие источники, как управлять фреймами и его элементами (таблицами, кнопками, контейнерами и прочими тегами) из родительского документа средствами JS (с учетом того что у фреймовых элементов будут такие же имена, id и class как у его родителя).
2. Как избежать явного указания имен для фреймов, а просто указывать что надо загрузить родительскую страницу (с кнопками и таблицей).
3. Как избежать зацикливания кода, если родительский документ "родит" фрейм, тот в свою очередь еще один "родит" фрейм и т.д. (остановить рекурсию своего рода "рождения" фреймов). Помогите с этими проблемами, друзья.

Comment: джаваскриптlocation.hrefвампоможетвследующийразвообщебезпробеловпишитевопросчтобыудобнеечитатьбыло

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. location.href - это ответ я так понимаю на второй мой вопрос (проблему). А что с остальными? И насчет слитного текста, я вроде разбил на два абзаца, вопрос и раздел "пытался". Единственное что пункты писал без перехода на новую строку.

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое фрейма недоступно из родительского документа, т.е управлять содержимым никак нельзя

Comment: неправда ваша. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PmRZM/

Comment: ну да в принципе, если на одном домене то можно